# Rehandle ASPX Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, httphandler, httpmodule

I want to know if there is a way to alter the markup for an aspx page before it goes to the client. I'm creating a sort of test CMS thing where I am going to use proprietary tags like  to denote sections of content that can be edited. Obviously I dont want the tags in the markup once it's sent to the client so I need to remove it before hand. So I want to know if there is a way to catch the page either before or after IIS handles it and change the markup.

Thanks!

Comment: IOW you want to hack a free product version?

Comment: I don't know is that how you would put it into words? That's not really along the lines of what I was thinking at all. Could you clarify your critism a bit?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a HttpHandler.